# Convert Existing grid.Panel to tree.Panel

Tags: extjs

I have a grid, that has dynamic column generation, my problem is that after I created it, I realized that I need tree.Panel instead of grid.Panel with same columns.

Code is pretty straightforward: one listener, one controller function that generates columns array which is used to reconfigure view.

Now this works with grid.Panel, columns are being generated, but not with tree.Panel. I get no errors, nothing to point out my mistakes...

grid.Panel:

[image]

tree.Panel:

[image]

view:

```
Ext.define('x.view.valuegrid.valuegrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel', //old grid version
    //extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel', <-- not working

    requires: [
        'x.view.valuegrid.valuegridModel',
        'x.view.valuegrid.valuegridController'
    ],

    xtype: 'valuegrid',

    viewModel: {
        type: 'valuegrid'
    },

    controller: 'valuegrid',

    enableLocking: true,
    //useArrows: true,
    //rootVisible: false,

    listeners: {
        beforerender: 'loadColumns'
    }
});
```

viewController code generating columns:

```
    var columns = [];

//create first column
var firstColumn = {//xtype: 'treecolumn', 
                   text: firstColumnData.label,
                   width: firstColumnData.width,
                   menuDisabled: true,
                   locked: true};
columns.push(firstColumn);

//create dimension columns
for(i = 0; i < dimensions.length; i++){
    var dim = {text: dimensions[i].label,
               width: 150, //parseInt(dimensions[i].width),
               menuDisabled: true,
               locked: true};
    columns.push(dim);
}                       

//create value columns
for(i = 0; i < groups.length; i++){
    var group = {text: groups[i], menuDisabled: true};
    var valCols = [];
    for(j = 0; j < valueColumns.length; j++){
        if(valueColumns[j].group == groups[i]){
            valCol = {text: valueColumns[j].label, 
                      width: 75,
                      menuDisabled: true}
            valCols.push(valCol);
        }
    }
    group.columns = valCols;
    columns.push(group);
}          

//reconfigure new columns
grid.reconfigure(null, columns);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem, all I needed was to add `columns: []` to view. 
Though I wonder, why wasn't this a problem for grid.Panel? If anyone can properly explain this to me, I will accept it as an answer.